# Why can't I use branched path tracing?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Why can't I use branched path tracing?

[image: its grayed out]

Comment: I realize this question is old, but in case you're still looking for an answer.. Is this an official build from blender.org?

Comment: yes it is fixed now sonce i updated, but it was official